# Trying to access stored procedure in PHP from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I created a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin named `Ratio_Viewer`. It takes in one parameter which is a stock ticker. I tested it in phpMyAdmin and I received the correct tuples. Now I am trying to incorporate that into my php files. I have a page where you enter a ticker and it takes you to another page which is supposed to display you the data based upon the stock ticker you entered. Nothing is getting returned. My code is:

```
require 'connection.php';
$sql = "CALL Ratio_Viewer('" . $_REQUEST["ticker"] . "')";

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
  echo "error: " . $mysqli->error . "<br>";
  exit;
}

echo ($result->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: the output is one row consisting of the values (assetTurnover, inventoryTurnover, cashConversionCycle, currentRatio, quickRatio, debtEquity, debtAssets, profitMargin, operatingMargin, returnOnAssets, returnOnEquity) and they are all values pertaining to the stock ticker

Comment: I mean, what is the output of the code you have shown above? There should be either "Array" or a mysql error, right?

Comment: Oh my bad, the output is "Array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working.

```
echo ($result->fetch_assoc());
```

will simply print "Array". PHP does not print arrays in a readable format in this case.

You can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) or implement a loop to print the data you want. For example,

```
foreach ($result->fetch_assoc() as $k => $v) echo "$k is $v <br>";
```

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection).

Comment: Nothing is getting printed. I also used vardump to check to see whats happening and im getting          object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(11) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: That is the `$result` - calling `fetch_assoc` will return your array of data (the next row each time the function is called) - see the first example on  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php